# SQL query for a mapping table to convert directly to JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL mapping table which holds relations between employees in the company - team leaders and team members. The table called `leaders` simply looks like this:

```
leader_id | employee_id
    1     |      15
    1     |      21
    1     |      26
    2     |      76
    2     |      41
```

Both columns are foreign keys to the `person` table which holds information like `name`, `dob`, etc.

The goal is to create a JSON with data as follows:

```
{
  1: {name: "John Doe",
      person_id: 1,
      employees: {
        15: {name: "Oliver Queen",
            person_id: 15
        },
        21: {name: "Barry Alan",
            person_id: 21
        },
        26: {name: "Solomon Rondon",
            person_id: 26
        },
      }
  },
  2: {name: "Papi Hans",
      person_id: 2,
      employees: {
        76: {name: "Ashley Young",
            person_id: 76
        },
        41: {name: "Amberly Smith",
            person_id: 41
        }
      }
  },
}
```

I do that easily enough by writing a query with a couple of joins to connect the data from the `person` table to the `leader_id` and `employee_id` respectively then iterate the result row by row to create the JSON.

My question is if there is a way to write the query so it brings up the results in ready-to-format-for-JSON format so that I don't have to iterate row by row to build it? And if there is, would that be more efficient?

Comment: would help https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=83657e6762b3071547dd2bedf34b4738)

```
SELECT
    json_object_agg(person_id,                                           -- 5
        -- 4
        json_build_object('name', name, 'person_id', person_id, 'employees', employees)
    )
FROM (
    SELECT
        l.leader_id as person_id,
        p1.name as name,
        json_object_agg(l.employee_id,                                   -- 3
            json_build_object('name', p2.name, 'person_id', p2.id)       -- 2
        ) as employees
    FROM
        leader l
    JOIN person p1 ON l.leader_id = p1.id                                -- 1
    JOIN person p2 ON l.employee_id = p2.id
    GROUP BY l.leader_id, p1.name
) s
```

1. Joining the `person` table to get the names
2. Create JSON objects for each employee
3. Aggregate these json object by grouping it by their leader into one JSON object
4. Create JSON objects for leaders using the employee
5. Aggregate all leader object into one single JSON object

---

In this case (4) can be shortened into

```
row_to_json(s)
```

---

Further reading: [Postgres JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), [Postgres JSON aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using this table of persons:

```
                 Table "public.emp"
  Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 person_id | integer |           | not null | 
 name      | text    |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "emp_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (person_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "leaders" CONSTRAINT "leaders_employee_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES emp(person_id)
    TABLE "leaders" CONSTRAINT "leaders_leader_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (leader_id) REFERENCES emp(person_id)
```

you could for example query like this:

```
SELECT json_agg(q)
FROM (SELECT le.person_id,
             le.name,
             json_agg(row_to_json(ee)) AS employees
      FROM emp le
        JOIN leaders l ON le.person_id = l.leader_id
        JOIN emp ee ON ee.person_id = l.employee_id
      GROUP BY le.person_id, le.name
     ) AS q;

                                                                             json_agg                                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"person_id":1,"name":"John Doe","employees":[{"person_id":15,"name":"Oliver Queen"}, {"person_id":21,"name":"Barry Alan"}, {"person_id":26,"name":"Solomon Rondon"}]}, +
  {"person_id":2,"name":"Papi Hans","employees":[{"person_id":76,"name":"Ashley Young"}, {"person_id":41,"name":"Amberly Smith"}]}]
(1 row)
```

Comment: `json_agg` puts the elements into arrays. That's not how the TO's example look like - but maybe it would be a good idea nonetheless

Comment: The JSON in the question is syntactically incorrect, so I interpreted it liberally.